# Uploading file through PHP (with lighttpd) not working properly

Tags: php, file, upload, size, lighttpd

I configured PHP and lighttpd to take a maximum of 9MB a couple weeks back and it worked perfectly fine. I used the following lines:

php.ini: `upload_max_filesize = 9000`
lighttpd.conf: `server.max-request-size  = 9000`

Now I need to support uploading files of up to 16MB. So, I changed the files to the following:

php.ini: `upload_max_filesize = 16000`
lighttpd.conf: `server.max-request-size  = 16000`

It does not work properly. It is supposed to upload the files to /tmp/tmp in pieces, then reconstructs them into one in /tmp. The pieces go into /tmp/tmp but are never rebuilt, just deleted. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Since you've posted no code, no I have no idea why. What makes you think the files will be assembled in this way? It's not something that PHP will do for you automatically.

Comment: That is how my uploading is configured. It worked great until I made the max file size larger

Comment: Well, changed my php.ini file to `upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M` and it works perfectly fine...now sure why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably assuming that the PHP config value is in *kbytes*. According to the PHP documentation for upload_max_filesize, it is in *bytes*.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize, which states:

> upload_max_filesize - integer
>
> The maximum size of an uploaded file. When an integer is used, the
>   value is measured in bytes.

Also refer to the PHP FAQ for other values that you can use for this and other config values:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes